# What is the best way to share methods across classes in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have several view controllers and table view controllers that I push from my root view controller. In all of these I'd like to use a custom back button in the navigation controller. Instead of copying the method to set up my back button into each class, file, I've created a helper class with a class method that does the setup. The code below works, but I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way. Is there a better way to achieve this? Also, I'm still duplicating the -(void)myCustomBack method in all my classes and was wondering if there's a way to avoid that as well.

```
@interface NavBarBackButtonSetterUpper : NSObject
+ (UIButton *)navbarSetup:(UIViewController *)callingViewController;
@end

@implementation NavBarBackButtonSetterUpper

+ (UIButton *)navbarSetup:(UIViewController *)callingViewController
{
    callingViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_textured_30"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];

    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];

    [backButton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter-Bold" size:12];
    backButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,-1);

    UIView *customBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    [customBackView addSubview:backButton];

    callingViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customBackView];

    return backButton;
}
@end



@interface MyCustomTableViewController : UITableViewController
@end

@implementation MyCustomTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *backButton = [NavBarBackButtonSetterUpper navbarSetup:self];

    [backButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(myCustomBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)myCustomBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end


@interface MyCustomViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation MyCustomViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *backButton = [NavBarBackButtonSetterUpper navbarSetup:self];

    [backButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(myCustomBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)myCustomBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you everbody for your responses and pointing me in the right direction. I ended up making a category of UIViewController that contains the methods that I want to use across my other classes. If there's a more elegant way of doing this, I'm happy to hear suggestions. This is what I went with:

```
// UIViewController+BackButtonSetup.h

@interface UIViewController (BackButtonSetup)
- (void)backButtonSetup;
- (void)myCustomBack;
@end


// UIViewController+BackButtonSetup.m

@implementation UIViewController (BackButtonSetup)

- (void)backButtonSetup
{
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    // A Bunch of code to set up the custom back button

    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myCustomBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (void)myCustomBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end


// MyCustomTableViewController.m

#import "UIViewController+BackButtonSetup.h"

@implementation MyCustomTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self backButtonSetup];
}
@end


//MyCustomViewController.m

#import "UIViewController+BackButtonSetup.h"

@implementation MyCustomViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self backButtonSetup];
}
@end
```

Comment: Good choice. This pattern has served me very well and I've never regretted using it. Since I notice this is your first question, you should mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check mark. Either Josh Caswell's or your own answer would make good choices in my view, but it's your decision alone, obviously. Good first question, hope to see you keep contributing, best of luck.

Comment: @CarlVeazey - thanks! As this is my first question, I'm still a bit uncertain of the proper etiquette for marking an answer. I did read all answers and took them all into consideration while I went and researched how to create a category. Plus, I wanted to wait for responses, and a possible better solution to the problem. But at this point I think what I have works well.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the solution to your problem would be inheritance.

You could create a subclass of `UIViewController` and have all of your custom view controllers inherit from this custom subclass. The "parent" subclass would have the `-(void)myCustomBack` as well as the setup code and you wouldn't need to repeat it anymore.

Comment: This.  You could also use categories or protocols, but subclassing seems like the easiest way in this instance.  You would only need to override methods if their implementation changed depending on the object.

Comment: This means you'd have to subclass both view controller and table view controller, so there'd still be some duplicate code

Comment: Would I need to create subclasses for both `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController`? I'd still be duplicating the code in two places then.

Answer (score 2):

The setup method doesn't really need to be in a separate class; I'd say you should make that a function.

The `myCustomBack` method, as long as it's exactly the same in all your subclasses, can easily be put into a category on `UIViewController`:

```
@interface UIViewController (DylanBack)
- (void)DylanCustomBack;
@end

@implementation UIViewController (DylanBack)
- (void)DylanCustomBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

(Use an initialism for a prefix, made from either your name, or the name of the company or project. Even though it's ugly, you need to avoid any possibility of collision. Category collisions clobber methods and will produce gnarly bugs.)

As long as you're doing this, you can also put the helper method into the category too. Turn it into an instance method and just use `self` instead of a passed-in controller.

Then all your subclasses will inherit the methods and you can use them as if you had defined them there. If any of the classes do need to specialize somehow, you can override.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much better way to go about this: Use the [`UIAppearance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. You can set up all those properties and have every back button which is contained in either a custom view type, or any navigation bar, inherit the look.

[Here's a screencast that will help you](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/21-customizing-uinavigationbar). Some of the code from there:

```
UIImage *back = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-backbutton.png"];
back = [back stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:ArrowLeftCap topCapHeight:0];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[CustomNavigationBar class], nil]
               setBackButtonBackgroundImage:back
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Note that that `CustomNavigationBar` class can just be `UINavigationBar`, which will cause all back buttons to get that appearance.

The one thing you might not be able to do with this is the "Back" title. That would have to be in all your view controllers.

Comment: Oh, you did answer it before I finished my answer.

Comment: The reason I went down this road is so I could change the title of the back button, or change it to a "home" image instead of having a label. Unfortunately it's not doable with the `UIBarButtonItem`. I was only able to do it by using a custom view. I am using the `UIAppearance` protocol for all my other buttons, and the navigation bar itself.

Answer (score 0):

In most languages, the easist solution is to have several `Utils` classes with static (class) methods.

In Obj-C, the common way is using categories.

In your example, creating a category on `UIBarButtonItem`, e.g. `UIBarButtonItem (CustomizedButtons)` with a method `+(UIBarButton*)customBackButton` would be much better.

However, there is a simpler way.
You can modify the appearance of all of your back buttons in one place, let's see an example

```
NSDictionary* titleAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIFont titilliumBoldWithSize:14.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                    [UIColor colorWithIntegerRed:181 green:201 blue:210], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                    [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                    nil];

NSDictionary* titleAttributesHighlighted = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               [UIFont titilliumBoldWithSize:14.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                               [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                               [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                               [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                nil];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributesHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage* backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_button_back_bg"];
UIImage* backButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_button_back_bg_highlighted"];

UIEdgeInsets backButtonCapInsets;
backButtonCapInsets.top = 0.0f;
backButtonCapInsets.bottom = backButtonImage.size.height;
backButtonCapInsets.left = 14.0f;
backButtonCapInsets.right = 5.0f;

backButtonImage = [backButtonImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:backButtonCapInsets];
backButtonImageHighlighted = [backButtonImageHighlighted resizableImageWithCapInsets:backButtonCapInsets];    

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImageHighlighted
                                                  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Note you don't have to use custom views and no special back button selector.

Comment: Thanks for this - Yes I am using the `UIAppearance` protocol for all my other `UIBarButtonItem`s and I am using it for my back buttons on other view controllers. The problem is that you cannot change the title of the back button without using a custom view

Comment: Well, you cannot change the title into an icon but you can change the title. The title is the `title` property of the previous controller on the stack.

Comment: Right, I could change the title of the root view controller on `viewDidDisappear` and then reset it on `viewWillAppear`, but that seems a bit "hacky", but I suppose my current approach is also "hacky". But if I did choose to use an image instead of the title, I'd still need to use a custom view.

Comment: @Dylan True, even it's an uncommon use case because it goes away from the iOS design. I think a category would be the best for you.